# Apollo Client: retrieving the results from a query with errors

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using the GraphQL Apollo Client. And I'm trying to retrieve the results from a query with errors.

[GraphQL response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIV5I.png)

How do I retrieve the data, even when an error is returned in the same response?

This automatically catches the error. Instead, I want it to access the data.

```js
this.client.query({
  query: gql(query),
  variables: variables
}).then(function ({ data }) {
  return data;
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Couldn't find anything in Apollo docs about this. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include a snippet of your schema? Because the error message indicates that `custom_attributes` is of a `String` scalar type.

Comment: This is not really relevant for me anymore, but if you want to ignore errors in Apollo you could probably use the errorPolicy option. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html#policies for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## if you stumble here in future

In Apollo-client there are various error types as follow:
1. GraphQL Errors,
2. Server Errors,
3. Transaction Errors,
4. UI Errors,
5. Apollo Client Errors.
As @ Alexander Schoonderwaldt you can learn about this errors and error policy [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4552)

You can handle/catch graphql errors using code below. If the values returns `undefined`, its no longer a graphql error. You need to investigate. You may have network error that returns `Error CONNREFUSED` or others.

```
    .query({
      query: myquery
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data.user);
      return { loggedInUser: data };
    })
    .catch(errors => {
      // Fail gracefully
      console.log(errors.message); // log grapgql error
      return { loggedInUser: {} };
    });
```