# GraphQL best practice on redacting fields that require authorization

Tags: error-handling, graphql

Consider a `User` type, with an `email` field that, for certain "anonymous" users, should only be accessible if the request was properly authorized. Other users are fine with having their email publicly displayed.

```
type User {
  name: String!
  "Anonymous users have the email only accessible to admins"
  email: String!
}
```

What are the pros and cons of these two approaches for handling that field in the `email` resolver for anonymous users?

1. `throw` if the request is unauthorized. In that case,

   - `email` needs to be declared as nullable `String` instead of `String!`, [or the entire query will error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778096/how-to-return-both-error-and-data-in-a-graphql-resolver/52780113?noredirect=1#comment108893874_52780113).
   - The client may want to match [the `errors`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603523/apollo-client-retrieving-the-results-from-a-query-with-errors) to the `data`. Because non-anonymous users will have their email accessible without authorization, `errors` and `data` may have different numbers of elements, so this matching seems **impossible**, at least with apollo-server, which doesn't return anything in each `errors` element that would indicate to which `user` it belongs.
   - `email` will be misleadingly `null` for anonymous users, confusing the situation with that of the email never having been added in the first place. Remember that `email` needs to be `String`, not `String!`, so a `null` email is reasonable.
   - There is a clear `errors` array in the response, so this feels like the "proper" approach?
2. return the email in a redacted form, e.g `[NOT AUTHORIZED TO ACCESS THIS USER'S EMAIL]`.

   - This keeps the objects intact with clear errors for sensitive emails, instead of misleading "null" emails.
   - `email` can stay non-nullable
   - No need to try to match `errors` with `data`.
   - There is no explicit `errors` array in the response, so this feels like a hack.

Note that for arrays, returning a `REDACTED` form is not an option, because the query may ask for a field within the array (e.g. `{ anonUsers { email } }`). The only option there is to return `[]` (directly or by `throw`ing).

Am I missing anything? Is there prior work on this topic? How can I make a decision?

Comment: Would union types be a good use case? You can have a normal `User` type and a `AnonymousUser` type, and maybe have some field that separates them like `is_anonymous`. So maybe `AnonymousUser` does not have an email field, while `User` has it.

Comment: @A.Lau: that skirts the problem. Let's say all users are anonymous, and only authorized requests can see the `email`; then the point about matching `errors` to `data` is moot, but the others remain.

Comment: maybe for `AnonymousUser` `email` can be an object so then you can show whatever message/error codes you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar recently, what seemed to work best was to create an interface for the base user type.

```
interface UserInformation {
  id: ID!
  userName: String
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String
  avatarImage: String
  city: String
  ...
}
```

Then you'd have two separate implementations of it:

```
type UserPublic implements UserInformation {
  id: ID!
  userName: String
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String
  avatarImage: String
  ...
}
```

```
type UserPrivate implements UserInformation {
  id: ID!
  userName: String
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String
  avatarImage: String
  friends: [UserInformation!]
  pendingFriends: [UserInformation!]
  phone: String
  email: String
  birthday: DateTime
  ...
}
```

All your other queries and types use the `UserInformation` base interface type when exposing Users. Then your graphql server simply returns either `UserPublic` or `UserPrivate` depending on what type of access the user has.

On the client side you query it like this:

```
query SomeQuery {
  getSomeData {
    user {
      id
      userName
      firstName
      lastName
      avatarImage
      ...on UserPrivate {
        email
        phone
      }
      ...
```

You can then check client-side whether the returned type of a field (`__typename`) was `UserPublic` or `UserPrivate` and act accordingly.